# Playwright VSCode gives `No tests found` message

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright, playwright-test

I've installed the Playwright vscode extension but when I go to the testing area I get a "No tests have been found in this workspace" message. But when I run `$> playwright test` on the CLI it works like a charm. The weird thing is, that some time ago it was perfectly working in VSCode.

[image]

When I click the reload icon I get

[image]

But then after a couple of seconds I get back where I started.
When I click the blue button I go to the list of extension

[image]

I'm not very sure what I am suppose to install here. Also, it did work in the past already.

This is the extension I installed for Playwright:

[image]

Any suggestion what is going on here in my VSCode?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem...

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue today and below is the steps I did to make this work, I hope this helps someone.

- I first tried the Command Pallete reload window and that didn't fix it.
- I completely closed vscode, opened my terminal and traversed into the folder and opened vscode with `code .` and it fixed it

I'm using nvm with node v14.19.0 and vscode v1.77.0

Comment: worked for me!!! yay thank you so much :D

Answer (score 4):

Check your playwright.config.ts and make sure `testDir:` is pointing to the folder with all your tests in it.

```
export default defineConfig({

  quiet: false,

  expect: {
    timeout: 30 * 1000,
  },
  

  testDir: './e2e',  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 3):

Please **update** your **Playwright version** (Version 1.28.1 at the time of this post) to the latest, (Steps below),

First Check your current version

```
 npx @playwright/test --version
```

Update to the latest version

```
npm install @playwright/test@latest
```

Install Browsers

```
npx playwright install
```

Check the updated version

```
npx @playwright/test --version
```

And also **install/update** the latest version of the **Playwright Test for VSCode** (v1.0.1 at the time of this post) and reload the IDE.
This can be done by simply as follows,

1. Go to Extensions
2. Search for "Playwright Test for VSCode"
3. Update or install the given latest version

It Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the only thing that helps me is VS code update, this extension works only on the latest version on VS code.
[tests section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKX7.png)

Answer (score 2):

Update Node on your system to the latest and it will resolve it. I had the same issue and by updating node, Vs Code immidiately detected all the test files and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the Microsoft extension installed and latest VSCode and got the same message in the Testing panel after using the "Install Playwright" command.

For me it was restarting VSCode completely that made the extension work. Note this was a full app restart and not just the "Developer: Reload Window" command.

Answer (score 1):

Update playwright.config.ts file and make sure that testDir:''

```
testDir: './TypeScript-PlayWright/tests'
```

Comment: This was it for me. I had a typo in one of my projects testDir path. Once that was corrected it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not your case, but as this is the first related question from Google, I'll give my resolution.

In my case I was using vite aliases (defined in vite.config.js).
Importing using these vite aliases would make my test files NOT detected by Playwright. Using resolved path was the solution:

From

```
import {mod1} from "@app/modules/mod1.mjs";
```

To

```
import {mod1} from "./../src/modules/mod1.mjs";
```

EDIT

Playwright now supports jsconfig.json and tsconfig.json where you can set up aliases. [Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17785#issuecomment-1828500041)

Comment: This was it for me.  I had a bad import.  `const CONSTANTS = require('./config');`  To check this yourself, comment out your imports then uncomment them one-by-one.  Keep doing this until your test disappears in the test list.  That's the import that's causing the problem.

Comment: @user2023861 See the edit, it will be easier with this

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're using a supported version of playwright.

In the "details" section, the extention I have installed says

> This extension works with Playwright Test version v1.19+ or newer.

I was using Playwright version 1.17, and faced this same issue. Updating to use version 1.19 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Playwright version 1.26.0

I actually had a github issue open
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/17687

Updating to Playwright version 1.26.1 solved the problem and tests were found once again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with a vs code which has been installed on a ubuntu box using the "ubuntu software" installer. This only installs snaps, which probably caused the issue. First I uninstalled the snap and deleted the .vscode folder in the users home directory.
After using apt for installation ( as explained here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-visual-studio-code-on-ubuntu-20-04/ ), the playwright plugin worked without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to use existing tests and the latest available version of VSCode and NodeJS just installed on my PC. It that the issue is in the lock files (yarn.lock and parameters-lock.json) contained conflicting requirements, I left only those files that already were with the tests and everything immediately worked after clicking the "update tests" button.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I was using vscode and node v16, once I switched to intellij and I could run the same tests with out any issue. Seems to be an issue with visual studio code editor.

Answer (score 0):

The above symptoms can also be caused by an error in the Playwright Test for VSCode extension start-up (playwright.config.ts issues, etc.).  Open the output window: View / Output -> Window (last item in the select) and look for messages from the extension, e.g.

```
2023-08-21 12:27:36.238 [error] [Extension Host] Error while listing files: c:\Users\brent\Source\Test\node_modules\@playwright\test\cli.js list-files -c playwright.config.ts {"message":"Project 'chromium' depends on unknown project 'xsetup'","stack":"Error: Project 'chromium' depends on unknown project 'xsetup'\n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue on Windows 10, on 1.37 Playwright version and vscode 1.81.1 2023
i update the vscode to latest version
i checked the configuration in playwright.config.js
closed the vs code completely
then i go to the the project folder and i delete .vscode if it there.
then right click on mouse and open this by vs code.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with Playwright version 1.38.1 on my Mac. I fixed it by uninstalling Visual Studio Code and then downloading the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This could when node isnt loading properly
I used to get this error when loading my shell

```
N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.
You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.`
```

Fix was to fix my node version to latest
`nvm alias default node`
and restart my terminal and vscode

Answer (score 0):

an update of the folder name in the playwright.config.js/ts worked for me

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by changing the playwright.config.ts to the default value. I must have had some issue there but couldn't find what.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled the vscode and installed again then restart my pc that worked for me

[playwright tests found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6z2Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue on latest version of VScode & Playwright. Closing and reopening solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).