# Playwright. The run test button does not appear

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-typescript

I'm starting to learn the Playwright. It's my first try to run a test. I've installed the Playwright Test for VSCode extention, then I've run

```
npm init playwright@latest --yes -- --quiet --browser=chromium --browser=firefox --browser=webkit
```

to install the browsers and the excemples. Now, when I'm opening the demo-todo-app.spec.ts I don't see the run button next to the test block

[The green triangle next to the test block does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgwlc.png)

I'm using macOS, node v18.17.1, VS Code version 1.80.0 (Universal) and Playwright Version 1.37.1.

How I can get the run test button?

I'd try also use v16 but it didn't help

I'd try all the solutions I've find here [Playwright VSCode gives `No tests found` message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100106/playwright-vscode-gives-no-tests-found-message) but nothing helped

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5tW3.png)

May you refer to the below answer of vmomryk
at the left panel, select Test explorer and click run there

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it by open `playwright.config.ts`, then change the `testDir` to `tests-examples` or to `testDir: './'`

```
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './',
// omitted
```